# Svg rendering using class not working with nested html inside foreignObject

Tags: css, angular, svg

Hi im having trouble with an svg object not rendering for some strange reason.

It does render if i look a the svg directly but not for some reason when used as a class reference.

htmlelement -> class -> svg **(Standard svg usage as class)**

svg -> htmlelement -> class -> svg **(a combined svg with multiple svgs, what ive done)**

htmlelement -> class -> svg -> htmlelement -> class -> svg **(fails to render only shows an empty box)**

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  viewBox="0 0 22 22"
>
<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" type="text/css" />
  <foreignObject width="22" height="22" overflow="visible">
    <xhtml:i class="file1 green"></xhtml:i>
  </foreignObject>
  <foreignObject width="22" height="22">
    <xhtml:i class="file2 blue"></xhtml:i>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

this works if i open svg or type the html directly, if i however add it to a file and reference the file using a class

```
.combined {
  background: url('combined.svg');
  display: block;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;

}
```

and then try calling it using for instance a  it doesnt work.

```
<i class="combined"></i>
```

link to stackblitz example [`https://stackblitz-starters-3mlvgg.stackblitz.io`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3mlvgg?file=src%2Fmain.html)

any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Trying to make a construct to use svg parts to build images and be able to modify the color of each part.

Comment: my default browser is firefox but im running into the same issue with chrome/edge also. Im open to suggestions on how to modify the html to still allow to use it as a class and be able to alter the color of the svg.

Comment: Ahh you're trying to use an external stylesheet in SVG used as an image. You'll have to inline the stylesheet into the SVG file.

Comment: i would suggest running the stackblitz to understand the problem in more depth as the is imported using the link statement

Comment: You can't use a link that refers to an external file in SVG when that SVG is used as an image. I'm not sure how to make that statement more clear.

Comment: so it i place the classes inside a style within the svg that should work ?

Comment: ive tried putting the classes inline but it still doesnt work som im quite clueless on what might be the issue. i assume you meant putting a style segment inside the combined svg with all the classes ?

Comment: yes, replace <link> by <style>

Comment: You might also circumvent this problem by avoiding `<foreignObjects>`. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/YzRWpgQ). You can apply the rounded rectangle svg as a mask to the `<i>` and the plus as a mask to a pseudo-element within.  I don't think there's a benefit wrapping both graphics in a combined svg that's mainly using HTML (in foreignObject)

Comment: @PeterSmith thank you that actually does what i want to, it also explains a few issues ive was experiencing when i tried that approach + i seem to completely forgotten about before and after.